# Binding forename and surname fields to a label?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a table associating an ID with a client's forename and surname (two separate fields). I have a TextBox on my form for a user to enter a client ID and I'd like a live update of the name displayed on a label, e.g.:

```
TextBox:  1  -->  Label: "Sam Pell"    (user types 1)
TextBox: 12  -->  Label: "Andy Other"  (user types 2)
```

I have two questions, really - I'm new to databinding in .NET:

- How can I make the contents of the TextBox update the displayed name on the Label?
- How can I display two separate fields (concatenated) within a single Label control?

I am currently using the Visual Studio data binding components; namely a `BindingSource`, `TableAdapter` and `DataSet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you are binding could have a readonly property that has a concatenated value.

```
public class Person
{
    string Forename { get; set; }
    string Surname { get; set; }
    string FullName 
    {
        get { return String.Format("{0} {1}", Forename, Surname); }
    }
}
```

Then bind FullName property to your label control.

In case you are using DataSet, then Add a custom column to your DataTable, with expression "forename + ' ' + surname". [More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx).

To update label you have to handle TextChanged event of your text box:

```
textBox1.TextChanged += () => label1.Text = (string) dt.Rows.Find(textBox1.Text)["columnName"];
```

where column name is the name of your new column.

Comment: I need the label to display the name of a client based on the ID entered into the textbox, just to just replicate the text.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the values from the database? You could perhaps modify your query to concatenate the values like this;

```
SELECT firstName + " " + surname FROM user
```

So you've just got one value to contend with when databinding.

Comment: I have a DataSet with TableAdapters and a BindingSource - I haven't written any SQL, so couldn't concatenate them like that?